# PyInstaller can't find module

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to package a test Python project using PyInstaller. The full source is available at https://github.com/xilanma/ohoh

All it does is import the aes and ecdsa module. When trying to package on Windows using PyInstaller, it builds the .exe but when I launch the .exe, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\ixcoin\dev\ohoh\dist>ohoh.exe
trying to import aes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: No module named aes
```

The full log is available at https://github.com/xilanma/ohoh/blob/master/README.md#some-logs

Does anyone know how to fix that problem? I'm testing using Windows 7 x86 in VirtualBox.

Answer (score -1):

I was having a similar issue being unable to import AES when using importing PyOpenSSL. AES was a hidden import that pyinstaller kept missing. This [google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyinstaller/6xD75_w4F-c) led me to the solution of using the develop branch of PyInstaller. A hidden imports file has been included in this branch that finds AES and includes it.

I did this by downloading the zip of the develop branch and unzipping it. PyInstaller could then be used with the following command:

```
python pyinstaller.py C:\path\to\my\script.py
```

All of the commands that come with the pip package can be used with the command above.

I hope that helps.